# ObjectMapper can't deserialize without default constructor after upgrade to Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

I have following DTOs:

```
@Value
public class PracticeResults {
    @NotNull
    Map<Long, Boolean> wordAnswers;
}

@Value
public class ProfileMetaDto {

    @NotEmpty
    String name;
    @Email
    String email;
    @Size(min = 5)
    String password;
}
```

`@Value` is a Lombok annotation which generates a constructor. Which means that this class doesn't have a no-arg constructor.

I used Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE and `ObjectMapper` bean was able to deserialize such object from JSON.

After the upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 I receive following exception:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of PracticeResults (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)`

Jackson version used in Spring Boot 1.4.3 is `2.8.10` and for Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7 is `2.9.2`.

I've tried to Google this problem but found only solutions with `@JsonCreator` or `@JsonProperty`.

So, why does it work with Spring Boot 1.4.3 and fails with Spring Boot 2? Is it possible to configure bean to behave the same way as the older version?

Comment: Just wondering, have you tried updating Jackson to the latest stable release 2.9.4? The changelog contains some specific fixes related map deserialization. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9.3

Comment: @LuisAguilar I've tried newer version but nothing changed. I have different DTOs with a few strings which also failed to deserialize. I think it is somehow related to Spring's configuration of object mapper, but I couldn't find anything related to default constructors.

Comment: What version of Lombok are you using in each case?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson spring 1.4.3 – lombok 1.16.12, spring 2 - lombok 1.16.20

Comment: @AndyWilkinson wow! I've tried new lombok version for spring boot 1.4.3 and got the same exception. Does it mean that lombok 1.16.12 generated no-arg constructor with `@Value` annotation?

Comment: *I've tried to Google this problem but found only solutions with `@JsonCreator` or `@JsonProperty`*, well that is the answer. Jackson requires those annotations on a constructor to know how to map the values into it or it needs a `default no-args constructor` just as the error message clearly states, and you have neither, that is why it is not working.

Comment: @solomkinmv, I couldn't reproduce your issue with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7, Jackson 2.9.2, Lombok 1.16.12, but have found a comment in the place where this exception is thrown: *"This is either a definition problem (if no applicable creator exists), or **input mismatch problem** (otherwise) since none of existing creators match with token."* are you sending the same JSON?

Comment: @solomkinmv, neither version of `@Value generates a default constructor, I've checked it out

Comment: Spring Boot 2 + Lombok 1.16.12 works for me. Lombok 1.16.20 breaks it.

Comment: this works for me - https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1563#issuecomment-362615072

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Due to breaking changes in Lombok version 1.16.20 you need to set the following property in your `lombok.config` file (if you don't have this file you can create it in your project root):

```
lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true
```

This is described in the Lombok changelog: https://projectlombok.org/changelog.

After that the @Value should be accepted again by Jackson.

You may be interested in following the related GitHub issue here, although it's about `@Data`: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1563

Comment: Very good point! :) I will only add here full description from lombok changelog:
`BREAKING CHANGE: lombok config key lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties is now deprecated and defaults to true, that is, by default lombok no longer automatically generates @ConstructorProperties annotations. New config key lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties now exists; set it to true if you want the old behavior. Oracle more or less broke this annotation with the release of JDK9, necessitating this breaking change.`

Answer (score 10):

One more way to solve this problem. Use Jackson [parameter names module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names), which is included in spring boot 2 by default. After this Jackson can deserialize objects. But it works only if you have more than 1 property in object. In case of single property I receive following error message:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `SomeClassName` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Because of the following:

> Marker annotation that can be used to define constructors and factory methods as one to use for instantiating new instances of the associated class.
>
> NOTE: when annotating creator methods (constructors, factory methods), method must either be:
>
> - Single-argument constructor/factory method without `JsonProperty` annotation for the argument: if so, this is so-called "delegate creator", in which case Jackson first binds JSON into type of the argument, and then calls creator. This is often used in conjunction with `JsonValue` (used for serialization).
> - Constructor/factory method where every **argument** is annotated with either `JsonProperty` or `JacksonInject`, to indicate name of property to bind to
>
> Also note that all `JsonProperty` annotations must specify actual name (NOT empty String for "default") unless you use one of extension modules that can detect parameter name; this because default JDK versions before 8 have not been able to store and/or retrieve parameter names from bytecode. But with JDK 8 (or using helper libraries such as Paranamer, or other JVM languages like Scala or Kotlin), specifying name is optional.

To handle this case with Lombok I've used following workaround:

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)))
class SomeClassName {...}
```

Comment: Not working,throws:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type definition for type `com.x.dto.y.PersonDTO`: Argument #0 has no property name, is not Injectable: can not use as Creator [constructor for com.x.dto.y.PersonDTO, annotations: {interface com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator=@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator(mode=PROPERTIES)}]
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3750) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue and the solution that worked for me what creating a *default constructor without fields* and the problem disappeared.

Comment: It becomes a problem if I wish to create non mutable object

Comment: @kapellan you're right. Check my answer, you may find it useful.

Answer (score 7):

***In case you have some final fields*** within your class and you would rather have Object creator to use specific constructor to deserialize your POJO along with `@Data` annotation, I suggest annotating the constructor with `@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)` and concrete required constructor parameters with `@JsonProperty("<field_name>")`. The example can be seen below:

```
package test.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Date;

@Data
public class KafkaEventPojo {
    private final String executionId;
    private final String folder;
    private final Date created_at;

    private Date updated_at;
    // ... other params
    
    /**
     * Instantiates a new Kafka event pojo.
     *
     * @param executionId the execution or flow id of the event lifecycle
     * @param folder      the folder to be retrieved
     */
    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public KafkaEventPojo(@JsonProperty("executionId") String executionId, @JsonProperty("folder") String folder) {
        this(executionId, folder, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    private KafkaEventPojo(String executionId, String folder, Date date) {
        this.executionId = executionId;
        this.folder = folder;

        this.created_at = date;
        this.updated_at = date;
    }
    
    // ... other logic
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem, but my solution did not involve adding this: `(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)`

What really solved my problem was the `@JsonProperty` within the Constructor.

My final result was this:

```
@Value
public class ServerTimeResponse {

    long serverTime;

    @JsonCreator
    public ServerTimeResponse(@JsonProperty("serverTime") long serverTime) {
        this.serverTime = serverTime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't you just copy https://stackoverflow.com/a/62799269/4942371

Answer (score 3):

Special annotation for `@Jacksonized` to the rescue - https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in native mode and getting the error is because of reflection to resolve the annotate your class with `@RegisterForReflection` and rebuild the application and run your error will be resolved

for information search on the [link](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#registering-for-reflection)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you need to add more the the `@Value` annotation to tell Lombok to write the `@JsonCreator` on the generated constructor

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_={@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)})
```

**Note** a slightly different syntax from other answers here if you are using JDK8+ (this is mentioned in the javadoc)

If you are using the freefair gradle plugin you also need to configure it to add constructor properties in `build.gradle`:

```
lombok {
    config['lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties'] = 'true'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded lombok version to : 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0' and it worked for me.

Comment: Hm, I don't see anything related in changelings