# SpringBoot deserialization without default constructor

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

During the last hours I read many StackOverflow questions and articles, but none of the advices helped. What I tried:

- Add @JsonCreator and @JsonProperty to both *Person* and *Employee* classes ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568353/how-to-de-serialize-an-immutable-object-without-default-constructor-using-object))
- Add @JsonDeserialize(using = EmployeeDeserialize.class) to *Employee* class  ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376304/right-way-to-write-json-deserializer-in-spring-or-extend-it))
- Add Lombok as dependency, set *lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true* and add @Data / @Value annotation to both *Person* and *Employee* classes ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330613/objectmapper-cant-deserialize-without-default-constructor-after-upgrade-to-spri))
- Finally, I did the deserialization manually:

  ```
  String json = "{\"name\": \"Unknown\",\"email\": \"please@work.now\",\"salary\":1}";
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Employee employee = objectMapper.readValue(json, Employee.class);
  ```

In this way I could deserialize the JSON, but as soon as I started my spring-boot-starter-web project and called

```
http://localhost:8080/print?name=unknown&email=please@work.now&salary=1
```

I got the good old BeanInstantiationException

```
Failed to instantiate [Employee]: No default constructor found
```

I run out of ideas. Does anybod know why this worked when I did the deserialization manually? And why it throws exception when I call the REST endpoint?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {
    @GetMapping("print")
    public void print(Employee employee) {
        System.out.println(employee);
    }
}

public class Person {
    private final String name;
    @JsonCreator
    public Person(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Employee extends Person {
    private final String email;
    private final int salary;
    @JsonCreator
    public Employee(
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("email") String email,
            @JsonProperty("salary") int salary) {
        super(name);
        this.email = email;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re implementing JSON deserialisation, yet you’re not using any JSON.

Change to use @PostMapping on your controller method and use something like Postman or cURL to send the JSON to your /print endpoint.

Comment: I think it should work with @GetMapping as well. If I create default constructors in Employee and Person classes, I can call the REST endpoint. So Jackon and Spring somehow do the deserialization automatically, but I don't know how I could override it.

Comment: It’s not using JSON. Jackson is not deserialising your object.