# Can not deserialize cached json data to AsyncResult

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-cache

I'm using spring cache with redis implementation, I have following method

```
@Async
@Cacheable(key = "#id")
public Future<Student> getStudent(String id){
  Student stu  = ...;
  return new AsyncResult<>(stu);
}
```

When I visit the method first time, the data is cached into redis in json format.

but when I visit it the second time, it occurs some error like this:

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

**[EDIT]**

I found a workaround : new a MyAsyncReslt.java which extends AsyncResult and add the NoArgsContructor.

Comment: It seems to be serialization problem. Do you properly implemented `Serializable` on `Student`?

Comment: yes I did implement Serializable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis Serializer uses Jackson under the hood [Class Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.html), the error:

> Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Seems to be outcoming from Jackson ([can't deserialize without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330613/objectmapper-cant-deserialize-without-default-constructor-after-upgrade-to-spri)):

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: **Cannot construct instance of `Type` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)**

Ensure you have your model class `Student` properly structured to be compliant with Jackson [Jackson - Object Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_object_serialization.htm) as it is used in `AsyncResult` via generics.

---

Edit in accordance to OP question:

> I found a workaround : new a MyAsyncReslt.java which extends AsyncResult and add the NoArgsContructor.

Spring's `AsyncResult` seems not to be properly implemented to be serialized with Jackson (check on Github [spring-projects/spring-framework: AsyncResult](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncResult.java)).

```
public class AsyncResult<V> implements ListenableFuture<V> {
    // ...

    public AsyncResult(@Nullable V value) {
        this(value, null);
    }

    private AsyncResult(@Nullable V value, @Nullable Throwable ex) {
        this.value = value;
        this.executionException = ex;
    }

    // Missing empty constructor to comply with Jackson requirements:
    public AsyncResult() {}

// ...
```

Until the issue will be patched you can extend Spring's `AsyncResult` and provide the required empty constructor. Freely use your custom AsyncResult in code.

Comment: The error say it cannot deserialize the AsyncResult  ,which is provided by spring and not under my controller

Comment: @rellocswood `AsyncResult<>` takes `Student` as generic, that's why I think the `Student` class might have Jackson's deserialization problems. Does the `Student` comply with all the needs of Jackson library? Does changing it makes any difference in outcoming error?

Comment: when i cache the Student directly it works,  when I add AsyncResult it fails

Comment: @rellocswood I have updated the answer with your recent discoveries and some explanation. You might consider making PR into Spring to patch the lacking functionality