# How do I deserialize to List of Strings or Boolean from an Object using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-11, jackson-databind

I was previously using jackson-databind 2.8.11.3 + Java 8 to deserialise a class ApiRequest, which was used as a request body in an API call. It has worked fine all the while and the JSON string is able to be generated.

In the Object params, either a List of Strings or boolean can be added.

Example JSON:

```
{
 "fields":[
  {
   "key": "colors",
   "values": ["blue","red"]
  },
  {
   "key": "metal",
   "values": true
  }
 ]
}
```

When I upgraded to use jackson-databind 2.13.2.2 + Java 11, and running the unit test for the generation of the JSON string, I ran to an issue where there was a bad JSON definition

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of 'com...' (no Creators, like default constructor,
> exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or
> property-based Creator) at [Source: (File) .. (through reference
> chain: com...ApiRequest["fields"])
>
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
>
> > 
>
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1904)

Below is a snippet of the class, which I have extracted and renamed:

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ApiRequest {
  private List<Fields> fields;

  @Data
  @Builder
  public static class Fields {
    private String key;
    private Object values;
  }
}
```

I have attempted to use JsonDeserializer to resolve the issue after reading up some other issues that others have posted online, but I was unsuccessful in resolving this.

Any suggestions/inputs would be greatly appreciated..

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ApiRequest {
  private List<Fields> fields;

  @Data
  @Builder
  @JsonDeserialize(using = FieldDeserializer.class) <-- added this
  public static class Fields {
    private String key;
    private Object values;
  }
}
```

```
public class FieldDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ApiRequest.Fields> {
  @Override
  public ApiRequest.Fields deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String key = node.get("key");
        JsonNode valuesNode = node.get("values");
        Object values = null;

        if (valuesNode.isArray()) {
            List<String> listValues = new ArrayList<>();
            valuesNode.forEach(elementNode -> listValues.add(elementNode.asText()));
            values = listValues;
        } else if (valuesNode.isBoolean()) {
            values = valuesNode.asBoolean();
        }

        return new ApiRequest.Fields.builder().key(key).values(values).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is because when you use `@Data`, Lombok will generate a constructor that takes arguments for all the fields, and Jackson needs a no-arguments constructor. Try adding `@NoArgsConstructor` to classes `ApiRequest` and `Fields`.

Comment: please update to include the full stacktrace.

Comment: This could be a case of needing to add lombok.config. See the top answer of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48543627/14607529

Comment: hi @samabcde, thanks for your comment. Have updated to include additional stacktrace.

Comment: hi @ODDminus1, thanks for your comment. have added lombok.config, issue is still present

Comment: Could you also add which version of lombok you are running?

Comment: My best advice here is: Just don't. Make your life *and* the lives of your API clients easier, and make sure your data structures are consistent. That means either include a propertly that'll define the type of the `values` field beforehand, or better yet, use two different property names.

Comment: thanks everyone for your kind help. Oleg Cherednik's answer has resolved the issue

Comment: sure @Jorn, will keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do set [@Jacksonized](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Jacksonized) along with [@Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)

```java
@Data
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class ApiRequest {

    private List<Field> fields;

    @Data
    @Builder
    @Jacksonized
    public static class Field {

        private String key;
        private Object values;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Oleg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77515980/7928721) if you are fine with [experimental feature](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/).
`@Jacksonized` is perfect match for this scenario.

Another way to solve this issue using stable API is by adding [`@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor) to `ApiRequest` and `Field`.

- As a drawback, this will expose the constructors to others, where `@Jacksonized` does not.
  This could also be rectified by adding `access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE` to the annotation (suppose jackson has access to your Module).

```java
@Data
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiRequest {
  private List<Fields> fields;

  @Data
  @Builder
  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public static class Fields {
    private String key;
    private Object values;
  }
}
```